# JavaScript array.push() stays empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an array of arrays (I'm working on a geometry algorithm and I need to return an array of polygons, the polygons themselves being arrays of vertices). I create my polygons and use a push method to add them to the list.

When I try to return my list it's always an array that contains a bunch of [undefined, undefined] arrays instead of the polygons.

My code looks like this

```
function functionName() {
    let polygonsList = [];
    console.log(polygonsList);
    let nextPolygonToCover = [{ lat: -4.915832801313164, lng: -4.684574604034425 }, { lat: -20.632784250388028, lng: -86.95019960403444 }, { lat: 75.49715731893085, lng: -27.887699604034427 }];
    console.log(nextPolygonToCover);
    console.log(polygonsList);
    polygonsList.push(nextPolygonToCover);
    console.log(polygonsList);
    return (polygonsList);
}
```

And here is a screenshot of my console:
[image]

- 928 is my `console.log(polygonsList)` after declaration.
- 930 is `console.log(nextPolygonToCover)` to check it was correctly declared.
- 931 is the `console.log(polygonsList)` just after.
- 933 is the last `console.log(polygonsList)`, just after the push.

This is a simplified version, where I replaced my nextPolygonToCover variable with a typical value and removed the calculations. The discrepancy in line numbers is due to the large amount of commented code. The issue is the same in both cases.

I also made the following tests:

- Copied the code to CodePen and there was no problem. https://codepen.io/compainl/pen/JjvBmVB
- Tried putting my test code from CodePen in another function without the comments and it did not work.
- Made a mistake when copying from CodePen and forgot to write the return and that, somehow, allowed the nextPolygonToCover array to be pushed into polygonsList. Adding the return caused the problem to return, which made the "successful" code unusable.

Here is a screenshot of my console for the case where `return (polygonsList);` is commented.
[image]

I don't understand how something can work on CodePen but not in my editor (or at least with no reason to think other elements of code would be interfering) and, more importantly how the presence or absence of return can be tied to the issue.

What am I doing wrong to end up in this situation?
Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: You're pushing all the `lat/lng` objects as a nested array in the array. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Why do you think the array is empty? The last log message is `[Array(3)]`. That's an array with 1 element, the element is a nested array with 3 elements. The nested array is `nextPolygonToCover`.

Comment: The nested `Array(3)` in the second screenshot is the weird case where the push works but I can't use it because I get there by removing my return.
In the first screenshot, the one with return, it says `[Array(3)]` but the content is `[undefined, undefined]`.
The nesting is intentionnal, because I have three levels: an object that represents a point, an array of points that represents a polygon, and an array of polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it's not working for you - works without issue in Chrome's console and in Node.

Anyways, here's a different approach which will help with your sanity:

```js
function functionName() {
  const polygon = [
    {lat: -4.915832801313164, lng: -4.684574604034425},
    {lat: -20.632784250388028, lng: -86.95019960403444},
    {lat: 75.49715731893085, lng: -27.887699604034427},
  ];
  let polygons = [];

  polygons = [...polygons, polygon]; // or polygons = polygons.concat(polygon)

  return polygons;
}

const polygons = functionName()

console.log(polygons)
```

Result:

[image]

The main idea is to *not* use `array.push` - don't mutate values, replace them via assignment. It's a core tenet of functional programming, and makes your code much easier to reason about as there are no side effects happening anywhere - you know something has changed because you've explicitly replaced it

Comment: Thank you ! 
The polygons = [...polygons, polygon]; option did not work but polygons = polygons.concat(polygon) did. Problem solved (I'm going to need to spend more time trying to figure out what happened though)

Comment: @Louri if `...` (array spread) didn't work, it could very well be that whatever's running your JS can't interpret that syntax. `array.concat` is safe all the way back to the 2000s, and performs the same job in this context